# STL vector implementation header size

Tags: c++, stdvector

Is there a requirement in C++ that

```
sizeof(std::vector<T>) == sizeof(std::vector<S>)
```

where `S` and `T` are arbitrary copy-assignable and copy-constructible types? For example, on my 64-bit Windows laptop with `GCC` we have

```
sizeof(std::vector<int>) == 

sizeof(std::vector<std::tuple<std::vector<double>, 
       int, std::map<int, std::string> > >)

== 24
```

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Once theoretical scenario: `S` and/or `T` are types where the compiler can do some sort of optimization on vector depending on the type_traits of `S` or `T`.  Thus this may yield a different vector size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no requirement that the size of all `std::vector` specializations be the same. The compiler is allowed to have different layouts and sizes for different specializations if it wants to.

In practice, one example is `vector<bool>` which happens to give a different result in at least one [instance](https://godbolt.org/z/PYsnnYGra):

```
std::cout << sizeof(std::vector<int>);   // 24
std::cout << sizeof(std::vector<bool>);  // 40
```